# aggregate dataframe subsets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, aggregation

I have the dataframe `ds`

```
CountyID  ZipCode   Value1    Value2    Value3 ...   Value25
   1        1         0        etc        etc          etc
   2        1         3       
   3        1         0       
   4        1         1       
   5        2         2       
   6        3         3       
   7        4         7
   8        4         2       
   9        5         1       
   10       6         0
```

and would like to aggregate based on `ds$ZipCode` and set `ds$CountyID` equal to the primary county based on the highest `ds$Value1`. For the above example, it would look like this:

```
CountyID  ZipCode   Value1    Value2    Value3 ...   Value25
   2        1         4        etc        etc          etc
   5        2         2       
   6        3         3       
   7        4         9       
   9        5         1       
   10       6         0
```

All the `ValueX` columns are the sum of that column grouped by `ZipCode`.

I've tried a bunch of different strategies over the last couple days, but none of them work. The best I've come up with is

```
#initialize the dataframe
ds_temp = data.frame()

#loop through each subset based on unique zipcodes
for (zip in unique(ds$ZipCode) {

    sub <- subset(ds, ds$ZipCode == zip)                                           
    len <- length(sub)                                                             
    maxIndex <- which.max(sub$Value1)                          

    #do the aggregation  
    row <- aggregate(sub[3:27], FUN=sum, by=list(                                  
        CountyID = rep(sub$CountyID[maxIndex], len),                           
        ZipCode = sub$ZipCode))                

    rbind(ds_temp, row)                                                            
}                                                                                  

ds <- ds_temp
```

I haven't been able to test this on the real data, but with dummy datasets (such as the one above), I keep getting the error "arguments must have the same length). I've messed around with rep() and fixed vectors (eg `c(1,2,3,4)`) but no matter what I do, the error persists. I also occasionally get an error to the effect of

> cannot subset data of type 'closure'.

Any ideas? I've also tried messing around with `data.frame()`, `ddply()`, `data.table()`, `dcast()`, etc.

Comment: In response to your comments, I've added an answer that displays the column names nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data.frame(aggregate(df[,3:27], by=list(df$ZipCode), sum),
  CountyID = unlist(lapply(split(df, df$ZipCode), 
    function(x) x$CountyID[which.max(x$Value1)])))
```

Fully reproducible sample data:

```
df<-read.table(text="
CountyID  ZipCode   Value1    
   1        1         0   
   2        1         3       
   3        1         0       
   4        1         1       
   5        2         2       
   6        3         3       
   7        4         7
   8        4         2       
   9        5         1       
   10       6         0", header=TRUE)

data.frame(aggregate(df[,3], by=list(df$ZipCode), sum),
  CountyID = unlist(lapply(split(df, df$ZipCode), 
    function(x) x$CountyID[which.max(x$Value1)])))

#  Group.1 x CountyID
#1       1 4        2
#2       2 2        5
#3       3 3        6
#4       4 9        7
#5       5 1        9
#6       6 0       10
```

Comment: Seems to work well on the sample data. Is there a way to preserve column names?

Comment: @aquamole you could do something like `names(newdf)[1:26]  <- names(originaldf)[2:27]`.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment on Frank's answer, you can preserve the column names by using the formula method in `aggregate`.  Using Franks's data `df`, this would be

```
> cbind(aggregate(Value1 ~ ZipCode, df, sum), 
        CountyID = sapply(split(df, df$ZipCode), function(x) {
            with(x, CountyID[Value1 == max(Value1)]) }))
#   ZipCode Value1 CountyID
# 1       1      4        2
# 2       2      2        5
# 3       3      3        6
# 4       4      9        7
# 5       5      1        9
# 6       6      0       10
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately I would have to spell out all 25 value column names.

Comment: No you don't.  Just use a subset of `names(df)` with `setNames`